# read_csv works in python 3.8 but get NA values in column X in 3.6

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use this line:

```
df = pd.read_csv(local_bad_parquet_path, delimiter='\t', index_col=False, dtype=dtypes)
```

My dtypes are as follows:

```
dtypes = {'high': 'Int32', 'low': 'Int32'}
```

The values in those columns are `<NA>` when I'm using the `python3.8` so in the file its just empty.

The code seems to work just fine in `python3.8` but for some reason I get

```
ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column X
```

when I use it on `python3.6`

Is there any reason for it to happen?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you should check if you use the same version of Pandas. I found that the newest Pandas support only 3.7+ - so your Python 3.6 may runs older version which may works in different way. Pandas doc: [Python version support](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html#python-version-support)